# How to move a exe file from kalivm to winvm?

Tags: virtualbox

I am using virtualbox for kali and win7 and Ubuntu as host. I tried copy paiste, cut paiste, didn't work. I should have the right setting for virtualbox to copy and paiste, because i can copy and paiste a url from iceweasle browse to libre office and that works. The book says drag and drop but he is using VMware, and I tried to drag and drop but I cant open the windows screen as I'm draging the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the VirtualBox Guest Additions in both of the virtual machines, than drag the file from one VM to the host, then drag it into the other VM. If you need help with the installation of the Additions under Kali, you can ask here, if you want. It can be a bit tricky, it's easier under Windows.

Comment: I have guest additions installed in kali, and i still cant drag out of kali to host.

Comment: You have to set the drag and drop function to "bidirectional". It's in one of the menus, can't remember exactly which one at the moment.

Comment: Drag and drop is already set to bidirectional.

Comment: Which version fo VirtualBox do you use? It works from 5.0 and up. For some reasons, the menu entrys were implemented already, the function itself not.

Comment: It's verion 4.3

Comment: That's what I thought already, which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: It's version 14.04

Comment: In case that it is a version prior to 15.10, you would have to download the VirtualBox package by downloading it from http://virtualbox.org/ , then reinstall the Guest Additions, and try again, I'm sure that it will work, as I am using it myself too. You can install the package by using the following command: sudo dpkg -i virtualbox.deb . You will have to specify the version number yourself. I would also recommend to install DKMS, you can do so using the command: sudo apt-get install dkms . I would do this before you install the VirtualBox deb package.